# Add automatic counter field to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have field containing sprint number.
I want to add to Jenkins additional field that will to grow one for each run of the job.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

BUILD_NUMBER is the right parameter which automatically increases with each build. If you want to reset the build number, you can do so by running the following script in the jenkins master groovy script console

```
jenkins = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
job = jenkins.getJob("JOBNAME")
println job.getNextBuildNumber()
job.updateNextBuildNumber(0)
println job.getNextBuildNumber()
```

This will set the build number to 0. You can then on rely on BUILD_NUMBER. If your requirement is only for a parameter that increases by 1 for each build, use BUILD_NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

See the [Jenkins documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project). The  BUILD_NUMBER environment variable does this and is provided by Jenkins to your job.

Comment: I don't want to use BUILD_NUMBER environment variable. I need numbering 0-20

Comment: @VladB You made no mention of that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have permissions to use [Jenkins shared libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) you can implement per job named counters slightly abusing [Hidden Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/hidden-parameter/) plugin. Create a global variable named `vars/counter.groovy` in your shared library like the following:

```java
import hudson.model.*
import com.wangyin.parameter.*;

// Implements per job named counters that
// can be manually controlled. Requires "Hidden Parameter" plugin:
// https://plugins.jenkins.io/hidden-parameter/

/**
 * Get current value
 */
int getCurrent(counterName)
{
    return getOrCreateParam(counterName).getCurrent();
}

/**
 * Get next value (previous value + 1)
 * When reset, it's always 0
 */
int getNext(counterName)
{
    return getOrCreateParam(counterName).getNext();
}

/**
 * Reset the counter (getCurrent() and getNext() will both return 0)
 */
void reset(counterName)
{
    getOrCreateParam(counterName).reset();
}

/**
 * Get current value and increment
 */
int getCurrentAndIncrement(counterName)
{
    def param = getOrCreateParam(counterName);
    def current = param.getCurrent();
    param.increment();
    return current;
}

/**
 * Get next value (previous value + 1) and increment
 * When reset, it's always 0
 */
int getNextAndIncrement(counterName)
{
    def param = getOrCreateParam(counterName);
    def next = param.getNext();
    param.increment();
    return next;
}

private def getOrCreateParam(String counterName)
{
    def job = currentBuild.rawBuild.getParent()
    def params = job.getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty.class)

    List<ParameterDefinition> newParams = new ArrayList<>();
    if (params != null)
    {
        for (param in params.parameterDefinitions)
        {
            if (param.name == counterName)
                return new ParamWrapper(param, false);
        }

        newParams.addAll(params.parameterDefinitions);
    }

    // "-1" value means that the parameter is initialized/reset
    def param = new WHideParameterDefinition(counterName, "-1", "");
    newParams.add(param);
    if (params != null)
        job.removeProperty(params);

    job.addProperty(new ParametersDefinitionProperty(newParams));
    return new ParamWrapper(param, true);
}

class ParamWrapper
{
    private WHideParameterDefinition param;
    private int currentValue;
    private boolean isReset;

    ParamWrapper(WHideParameterDefinition param, boolean isInitialized)
    {
        this.param = param;
        if (isInitialized)
        {
            currentValue = 0;
            this.isReset = true;
        }
        else
        {
            currentValue = parseWithDefault(param.defaultValue, 0);
            if (currentValue < 0)
            {
                currentValue = 0;
                this.isReset = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.isReset = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void reset()
    {
        param.defaultValue = "-1";
        currentValue = 0;
        isReset = true;
    }

    void increment()
    {
        incrementPrivate();
        isReset = false;
    }

    int getNext()
    {
        if (isReset)
        {
            param.defaultValue = "0";
            isReset = false;
            return 0;
        }

        incrementPrivate();
        return currentValue;
    }

    int getCurrent()
    {
        if (isReset)
        {
            param.defaultValue = "0";
            isReset = false;
            return 0;
        }
        
        return currentValue;
    }

    private void incrementPrivate()
    {
        currentValue++;
        if (currentValue < 0)
        {
            param.defaultValue = "0";
            currentValue = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            param.defaultValue = Integer.toString(currentValue);
        }
    }

    @NonCPS
    private static int parseWithDefault(String number, int defaultVal)
    {
        try
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(number);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return defaultVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your pipeline you can use it like the following:

```
@Library('MySharedLibrary@master') _

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo "MyCounter getNext: ${counter.getNext("MyCounter")}"
                echo "MyCounter getCurrentAndIncrement: ${counter.getCurrentAndIncrement("MyCounter")}"
                echo "MyCounter getCurrent: ${counter.getCurrent("MyCounter")}"
                echo "MyCounter getNextAndIncrement: ${counter.getNextAndIncrement("MyCounter")}"
                echo "MyCounter getCurrent: ${counter.getCurrent("MyCounter")}"
                counter.reset("MyCounter")
                echo "MyCounter reset"
                echo "MyCounter getCurrent: ${counter.getCurrent("MyCounter")}"
                echo "MyCounter getNext: ${counter.getNext("MyCounter")}"
                echo "MyCounter getNext: ${counter.getNext("MyCounter")}"
                counter.reset("MyCounter")
                echo "MyCounter reset"
                echo "MyCounter getNextAndIncrement: ${counter.getNextAndIncrement("MyCounter")}"
                echo "MyCounter getCurrent: ${counter.getCurrent("MyCounter")}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which will print:

```
MyCounter getNext: 2
MyCounter getCurrentAndIncrement: 2
MyCounter getCurrent: 3
MyCounter getNextAndIncrement: 4
MyCounter getCurrent: 5
MyCounter reset
MyCounter getCurrent: 0
MyCounter getNext: 1
MyCounter getNext: 2
MyCounter reset
MyCounter getNextAndIncrement: 0
MyCounter getCurrent: 1
```

You can conveniently find the counter as a parameter in your pipeline configuration UI, which you can tweak/delete (beware it should be an integer).